# Find "." and remove from the "." followed by 2 zero's

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column which contains below values. Need to find if it has "." and followed by 2 zero's. Once found remove from . and its 2 zero's.

## Value

5000

5000.00

5000.i

4000.00

## Desired output

5000

5000

5000.i

4000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex here:

```
df['Value'].replace('\.\d{2}','',regex=True)
```

---

```
0      5000
1      5000
2    5000.i
3      4000
Name: Value, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': ['5000', '5000.00', '5000.i', '4000.00']})
df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply(lambda x: x.split('.00')[0])
```

|  | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 5000 |
| 1 | 5000 |
| 2 | 5000.i |
| 3 | 4000 |

Comment: with this approach, one can also do `df['Value'].str.split("\.00").str[0]` :)